# Micronaut JDBCRepository Query only sending "true" as the query statement

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

I'm trying to set up a simple http filter that will track user's consumption of vendor data by upserting to a postgres database.

My connection to the database appears to work but any query is always received by the database as simply
`true`

I can see the log output in the database console whenever trying to execute a repo class query and the error from the postgres driver shows the same. So the connection is working.

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "true" at character 1`

`STATEMENT:  true`

My Entity with composite key looks like this

```
@Embeddable
public class MarketDataConsumptionId {

    public UUID accountId;

    public String accessType;

    public LocalDate consumptionPeriod;

    public MarketDataConsumptionId(UUID accountId, String accessType, LocalDate consumptionPeriod) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
        this.accessType = accessType;
        this.consumptionPeriod = consumptionPeriod;
    }

    public UUID getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public void setAccountId(UUID accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    public String getAccessType() {
        return accessType;
    }

    public void setAccessType(String accessType) {
        this.accessType = accessType;
    }

    public LocalDate getConsumptionPeriod() {
        return consumptionPeriod;
    }

    public void setConsumptionPeriod(LocalDate consumptionPeriod) {
        this.consumptionPeriod = consumptionPeriod;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        MarketDataConsumptionId mcd1 = (MarketDataConsumptionId) o;
        return Objects.equals(accessType, mcd1.getAccessType()) &&
                consumptionPeriod == mcd1.getConsumptionPeriod() &&
                accountId == mcd1.getAccountId();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(accountId, accessType, consumptionPeriod);
    }
}
```

```
@MappedEntity
public class MarketDataConsumption {

    @EmbeddedId
    public MarketDataConsumptionId marketDataConsumptionId;

    public ZonedDateTime tapeOpra;

    public MarketDataConsumption(MarketDataConsumptionId marketDataConsumptionId,
                                 ZonedDateTime tapeOpra) {
        this.marketDataConsumptionId = marketDataConsumptionId;
        this.tapeOpra = tapeOpra;
    }

    public MarketDataConsumptionId getMarketDataConsumptionId() {
        return marketDataConsumptionId;
    }

    public void setMarketDataConsumptionId(MarketDataConsumptionId marketDataConsumptionId) {
        this.marketDataConsumptionId = marketDataConsumptionId;
    }

    public ZonedDateTime getTapeOpra() {
        return tapeOpra;
    }

    public void setTapeOpra(ZonedDateTime tapeOpra) {
        this.tapeOpra = tapeOpra;
    }
```

My Repository Class

```
@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.POSTGRES)
public interface MarketDataConsumptionRepo extends GenericRepository<MarketDataConsumption, MarketDataConsumptionId> {

    @Query("SELECT count(*) FROM market_data_consumption")
    int getRowCount();

}
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ai.options.market</groupId>
  <artifactId>oai-market-api</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <packaging>${packaging}</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.11</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <jdk.version>16</jdk.version>
    <release.version>16</release.version>
    <micronaut.version>2.5.11</micronaut.version>
    <exec.mainClass>{MY_APPLICATION}</exec.mainClass>
    <micronaut.runtime>netty</micronaut.runtime>
    <postgres.version>42.4.1</postgres.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-netty</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-runtime</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.sql</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-jdbc-hikari</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <!--Postgres Driver-->
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>${postgres.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ai.options.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.redis</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-redis-lettuce</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.cache</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-cache-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.build</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <annotationProcessorPaths combine.children="append">
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-data-processor</artifactId>
              <version>2.0.0</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=ai.options.market</arg>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=oai-market-api</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

My application.yml datasource config

```
datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
    username: postgres
    password: mypass
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

I've tried following several different guides on micronaut data. I've tried using different Repository interfaces and different dependency versions and I've also tried adding micronaut-inject-java to the annotationProcessorPaths. I still always get the same result.

EDIT:

In testing workarounds I have discovered that the abstract class GenaricRepository implementation with JdbcOperations is working for me if I use a UUID is a single primary key instead of an embedded composite key.

https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/#dbcRepositories

This is my new repo class and I will be pursuing this implementation

```
@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.POSTGRES)
public abstract class MarketDataConsumptionRepo implements GenericRepository<MarketDataConsumption, UUID> {

    private final JdbcOperations jdbcOperations;

    public MarketDataConsumptionRepo(JdbcOperations jdbcOperations) {
        this.jdbcOperations = jdbcOperations;
    }

    @Transactional
    public Optional<MarketDataConsumption> getRowCount() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM market_data_consumption LIMIT 1";
        return jdbcOperations.prepareStatement(sql, statement -> {
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            var result = jdbcOperations.entityStream(resultSet, MarketDataConsumption.class).findFirst();
            return result;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue. Does the same thing happen if you run the query on the database directly (as in a SQL Query Console)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this. I use DBeaver as a means to interact with my databases outside of an API. My queries work their because the database is actually using the statement I give.

Comment: Your question lead me to more research and I am now able to send statements and get results back using an abstract class repository implementation with JdbcOperations and altering my entities to not use a composite key.

I was receiving errors where the column name for account id could not be read because it was trying to read it as market_data_consumption_id_account_id which is not the name of the column, it's just account_id.

I'm pursuing this implementation and looking more into composite keys